# What is $\textbf{P}(A)$ given $\textbf{P}(A\cap\overline{B})$ , $\textbf{P}(B\cap\overline{A})$ and $\textbf{P}(B)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

For events $A$ and $B$, we know that

$\textbf{P}(A\cap\overline{B}) = 0.2$,

$\textbf{P}(B\cap\overline{A}) = 0.1$,

$\textbf{P}(B) = 0.3$,

Find $\textbf{P}(A)$.

Comment: What is B’? I don’t understand

Comment: @FedericoFallucca B complement ; B^c

Comment: Hint: draw a Venn-diagram.

Comment: @drhab i drew one and understood that it becomes (A∩B)', However i dont understand where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\textbf{P}(A) = \textbf{P}(A\cap\Omega) = \textbf{P}(A\cap(B\cup\overline{B})) = \textbf{P}((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\overline{B})) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(A\cap\overline{B})\\\\
\textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(B\cap\Omega) = \textbf{P}(B\cap(A\cup\overline{A})) = \textbf{P}((B\cap A)\cup(B\cap\overline{A})) = \textbf{P}(B\cap A) + \textbf{P}(B\cap\overline{A})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Substracting both equations, one has
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(A\cap\overline{B}) - \textbf{P}(B\cap\overline{A}) \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A) = \textbf{P}(B) + \textbf{P}(A\cap\overline{B}) - \textbf{P}(B\cap\overline{A})
\end{align*}

Thus, according to the given data, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) = 0.3 + 0.2 - 0.1  = 0.4
\end{align*}

Comment: What is Ω? sorry im not familiar with this symbol

Comment: It denotes the sample space, the set consisting of all possible outcomes.

Comment: im just a little confused about the 0.3+0.2-0.1=0.4, what formula is that?

Comment: I will edit my answer in order to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks!! this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach.  Since
$$
B=(B\cap A)\cup(B\cap A')\ ,\\
(B\cap A)\cap(B\cap A')=\emptyset\ ,
$$
and you know $\ P(B)\ $ and $\ P(B\cap A')\ $, then you can calculate the value of $\ P(B\cap A)\ $ (can you see why?).

Now,
$$
A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')\ ,\\
(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap B')=\emptyset\ ,
$$
and you now know both $\ P(A\cap B)\ $ and $\ P(A\cap B')\ $, so you can calculate $\ P(A)\ $.