# Find P(A), given is P(at least one of two events occurs) and P(Exactly one of two occurs)

Tags: probability, statistics

Stuck on homework question.

Let A and B be two events.

P(A|B)=0.6

P(At least one of the two events occur)=0.8

P(Exactly one of the two events occur)=0.6

"Exactly one"  means either A or B but not both.

Find P(A).

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380874/what-is-textbfpa-given-textbfpa-cap-overlineb-textbfpb-ca) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  Please edit to include your attempts.

Comment: @lulu I have an exam tomorrow morning...i ask the question here and move on hoping someone will answer it so that i can learn how to do it.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram and stick appropriate numbers in appropriate regions.  That should help a lot.

Comment: @farooq1219 You will learn best by trying, and people will more likely help those they see trying to help themselves. Do as much as you can and then post your efforts and ideas for critique and assistance.

Comment: Also, another hint: "At least one" is $A\cup B$, while "exactly one" is $(A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B)$

Comment: Here's a start:  From $P(A \text{ or } B) - P(A \text{ xor } B) = ..8 - .6 = 2,$ you get $P(AB) = .2.$ Then $P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B) = .6$ you can find $P(B).$ From there, maybe with a Venn diagram, can you find $P(A)?$

Comment: @GrahamKemp i tried to use the equation you gave but i keep ending up at p(b)-p(a)... my midterm is in a few hours and i would really appreciate it if you could provide me with a solution instead of hints

Comment: @GrahamKemp however thank you very much for trying to help

Comment: @BruceET whats P(A xor B)

Comment: 'Exclusive or' = Exactly one of the two events = A or B but not both.

Comment: 'Exclusive or' = Exactly one of the two events = A or B but not both. // Also, A or B (.8) is the union of three disjoint parts A only (?), A and B (.2), B only (1/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B)&=0.6\\ \mathsf P(A\cup B)&=0.8\\ \mathsf P(A\oplus B)&=0.6\end{align}$$

Where $\oplus$ is XOR ("exactly one of"): $A\oplus B~{ = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B)\\=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^\complement}$

So $\mathsf P(A\oplus B) = \mathsf P(A\cup B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)~~$ (ie : the probability for "one *but* not both")

And you wish to find $\mathsf P(A)$

---

First use the definition of conditional probability to evaluate $\mathsf P(B)$.

Then use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to evaluate $\mathsf P(A)$.